# How to present UIAlertController in front of modal sheet in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to show an alert with a textfield from a modal in swift, but getting an error when I try to show it.

I have to use a UIAlertController because the default alert in Swift doesn't support Textfields currently.

I am calling my modal from my base view with

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingLocationSheet) {
                LocationSelectionView(selectedLocations: $locations)
                }
```

From my `LocationSelectionView`, I then call the alert as follows:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Location", message: "Enter Location Name", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addTextField { (name) in
      name.placeholder = "Bathroom"
}
let add = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { _ in
       print("add Location")
}
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive)

 alert.addAction(add)
 alert.addAction(cancel)

                    
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true)
                    }
```

but then I receive this error:

```
Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fc8a78c7c00> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x7fc8a800b8d0> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x7fc8a800b8d0>) which is already presenting <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7fc8a6e51980>.
```

I'm not quite sure how to get it to show here. I've also tried using an extension on the UIAlertController like this:

```
public extension UIAlertController {
func show() {
    let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    win.rootViewController = vc
    win.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1  // Swift 3-4: UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
    win.makeKeyAndVisible()
    vc.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

as well as getting the top most controller like so:

```
func topmostController() -> UIViewController? {
    if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        return topController
    }
    return nil
}
```

but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using the [built-in alert modifier](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-an-alert) instead

Comment: Why not just write a presented view controller and forget the "alert"?